# Custom Payment Method appear but is not available

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I'm trying to create a custom payment model, a simple one without database changes, but I have a problem, when I select it in the checkout it said:

> The request Payment Method is not available

Now, the debug:

- In `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` with `$this->getCode()`, I can't see my custom method
- In a observer, like above, I can't see my method
- In `template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml` I can see it

I suppose my `config.xml` and `system.xml` are working because:

- I can see it in the admin area and save it
- I can see the value in `core_config_data`
- I can see it in the checkout
- I compare with other extensions and it looks the same

Now in `Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php` inside `function isAvailable`
I put some logs and:

```
$isActive == 1
$isAvailable == 1
$isDeniedInConfig == ''
```

But still doesn't work.

My code:

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Pay>
            <module>0.0.1</module>
        </Namespace_Pay>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <pay>
                <class>Namespace_Pay_Helper</class>
            </pay>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <pay>
                <class>Namespace_Pay_Model</class>
            </pay>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <namespace_pay>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Title</title>
                <model>pay/store</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
            </namespace_pay>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <pay translate="label" module="pay">
                    <label>Label</label>
                    <sort_order>670</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New order status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_processing</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from applicable countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </allowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from Specific countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                    </fields>
                </pay>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Store.php (Model)**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Pay_Model_Store
    extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'pay';
}
```

Comment: Why you have written this ` if($quote->getAllVisibleItems() <= 2){ retur false;}` ? try to remove this and check

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have this part commented all the time in my code, I don't understand why I fount it in this way, but I think it's wrong too

Comment: please post your full code here which you have done for payment method so peoples can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child node in `<payment>` in your `config.xml` is incorrect since you're referring to you model as `pay` (not `namespace_pay`).

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Pay>
            <module>0.0.1</module>
        </Namespace_Pay>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <pay>
                <class>Namespace_Pay_Helper</class>
            </pay>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <pay>
                <class>Namespace_Pay_Model</class>
            </pay>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <pay> <!-- "namespace_pay" is incorrect -->
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Title</title>
                <model>pay/store</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
            </pay>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the correct answer, and I can't explain why, but for me works.

-In `system.xml` put `module="namespace_pay"`

-In `config.xml` inside helpers and models tags put namespace_pay:

```
<helpers>
    <namespace_pay>
        <class>Namespace_Pay_Helper</class>

<models>
    <namespace_pay>
        <class>Namespace_Pay_Model</class>
```

and:

```
<default>
    <payment>
        <pay>
           <model>namespace_pay/store</model>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm telling you. But obviously it doesn't matter whether you change ALL model alias  to fit one wrong line (from `pay` to `namespace_pay`) or change one line to fit ALL others (from `namespace_pay` to `pay`)...

Comment: With your answer only it doesn't work... in my code at least

Comment: ok, sorry, it's true

Comment: Don't worry - as said, both ways are valid. Since there is no 100% definition as per what your alias should look like I however would dent to to say that `namespace_pay` is anyway more preferable than just `pay` (since that will give a better hint of where the model is coming from)